# Declare Metal support requirement for MacOS application

Tags: macos, cocoa, metal

I'm preparing my app for the Mac App Store. The app depends on Metal and I do not want it to be installed on devices which do not have GPU capable enough. How do I specify this in Info.plist? I've found that on iOS this is possible with UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key, but this is not supported on macOS. Is there any way to declare Metal dependency? I doubt Metal requirement will be automatically deduced when I upload to the store.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible.

There is no macOS equivalent to iOS's device capabilities key. This is why games and other graphically-intensive apps often list additional system requirements in their descriptions.

One imperfect option is to set your deployment target to macOS 10.14 Mojave or newer, since Metal is supported on all Macs supported by Mojave (2012 and later).

When it comes to determining whether the system supports features not present in all versions of Metal, you should use the `supportsFeatureSet(_:)` method and related API to determine whether to use such features on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: This is my worst suspicion. So either I target 10.14 and higher and loose somewhere 25% installations (at curreent os share) or rely on app description and create a support hell as users do not care whether they have metal capable mac or not. It seems we moved to Metal too early.